# How to run f2py in macosx

Tags: python, bash

Hi I am trying to use f2py in macosx.
I have a homebrew python instalation and I have installed numpy using pip.
If I write on terminal `f2py` I get `-bash: f2py: command not found` but if I write in a python script `import numpy.f2py`it works well.
How can I solve this problem runing f2py directly from terminal?
Thank you!

Comment: `f2py` should have ended up installed into your Homebrew installation's `scripts` directory. Depending on how you've configured things, this may be `/usr/local/bin`, or it may be something like `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin`. If it's the latter, you can add that directory to the end of your path, or just symlink it manually to the former. If it's the former, and `/usr/local/bin` isn't on your path, it should be.

Comment: Thank you. In my case I solve the problem with an alias in my bash_profile `alias f2py="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.10.0.dev_fe7816d-py2.7-macosx-10.10-x86_64.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/f2py2.7"`

Comment: Yes, that works. But… that's an odd place for `f2py` to have gotten installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (installed numpy with pip on macosx, but got f2py not found). In my case f2py was indeed in a location on my $PATH (/Users/*username*/Library/Python/2.7/bin), but had no execute permissions set. Once that was fixed all was fine.